# ajax post multiple input groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have a form with 4 groups of checkboxes used to refine search results.  I want to be able to post an array for each checkbox group containing the id's of the checkboxes currently ticked.

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "/stay_in_belfast/accommodation",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
     subcategory_ids:$(":checkbox[name^='subcategory_ids[']").serialize(),                                                                                                 
     rating_ids:$(":checkbox[name^='rating_ids[']").serialize(),
     location_ids:$(":checkbox[name^='location_ids[']").serialize(),
     facility_ids:$(":checkbox[name^='facility_ids[']").serialize()
   },
   success: function( data ) {
   }
 });
```

When I post this though my array contains four variables as expected, except the data looks like:

```
subcategory_ids%5B%5D=22&subcategory_ids%5B%5D=23&subcategory_ids%5B%5D=24&subcategory_ids%5B%5D=26&subcategory_ids%5B%5D=27&subcategory_ids%5B%5D=28
```

If I use serializeArray each of the four post variables contain a name paired array with the input name and the value.  However the input name is always going to be the group name of the input for that group and therefore is of no real use to me. If I try this just sending one group through such as

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/stay_in_belfast/accommodation",
  type: "POST",
  data: $(":checkbox[name^='subcategory_ids[']").serialize(),                                                                                                 
  success: function( data ) {
  }
});
```

It shows up the the post as an array of the id's.  I can't figure out why it's different depending if I post through a single grouping or post through four groupings.

Basically all I want in my post is 4 arrays identified by their input group with each array contains a list of id's.  Am sure this is possible but I am just missing it.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what's causing your problem, but I can think of some things to try:
1.  Create the data object separately, outside of the call, and pass it in.
2.  Serialize the entire structure, not the individual properties.

Comment: Did you try `$("form#some_form_id").serialize()`?

Comment: Cheers @SalmanA.  Serialize on the entire form worked great. Thanks.

Comment: what you are showing is standard urlencoded form array format, are you needing json arrays or???  more details needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`jQuery.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function can be used to encode the contents of an entire form for submission. You can use the encoded string inside your AJAX requests like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/some-url",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#some-form").serialize() // returns name-value pairs, encoded as form data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, they have problems while using this:

```
url: "/foldername/file.php",
```

as i have to use always:

```
url: "foldername/file.php",,
```